# How to pass dynamic values to a constructor from another class which is injected as autowired object

Tags: spring-boot

How to pass dynamic values to a constructor from another class which is injected as autowired object?

```
@Service    
Class Test { 
    int a;
    String b;

    public Test(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

Class Sample {
    @Autowired
    Test test;
}
```

How can I pass values to `Test` class constructor from `Sample` class?

Answer (score 0):

Spring beans are immutable by idea. 
If your Test instance is different for every instance of Sample class, it don't have to be a spring bean, especially if some fileds on the Test instance depend on values from the Sample instance.

Maybe a solution would be to change your Test class scope so you can create multiple instances, but you have to explain more what you mean by dynamic values.